# C# Get application url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the application url in C#. I have tried using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

But that only returns me "/". I am trying to get the full url of application's base url, which may or may not simply be "something.com". In some cases, depending on the environment, it is "something.com/foo/bar".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is your application running as a virtual directory, or behind a reverse proxy? `Request.ApplicationPath` has always worked for me in the past.

Comment: Throw a debugger somewhere and inspect `HttpContext.Current.Request` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`- you'll find a ton of useful properties which give you the URL formatted lots of ways - one of them is probably going to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wouldn't the `RawUrl` be enough for you?

If that gives you too much, you could try

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
```

Comment: `VirtualPathUtility` not found in mvc view!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
```

Comment: this much worked fine for me Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority. +1 for this :)

Comment: This will not work when application is starting e.g. in Global.asax methods, class static initializers ...